# class 'pkg_resources.ExtractionError'

Tags: python, mysql, cgi

I am using python cgi-bin and mysql. I am trying to fetch values from mysql db. But i dont know why this is coming. Tried a lot but failed to know whats this is. I also checked on python command line by typing : `import MySQLdb` and it gave me no error.

Note: I am working on windows 8.

File name: **cgisql.py**

My code:

```
#!C:\Python27\python

import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()


p= """Content-type: text/html\n
<html>
<h1> hello</h1>
</html>
"""
print (p)

import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=3306, user="root", passwd="",db="project")


cursor = db.cursor()
cursor2 = db.cursor()
# execute SQL select statement
#sql = "SELECT stid,firstname FROM student WERE stid IN(SELECT stid FROM stobt WHERE stid=%s" % (0)

sql2 = "SELECT stid FROM student  WHERE firstname = '%s'" % ('User')


# Execute the SQL command

cursor2.execute(sql2)
# Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.

result2 = cursor2.fetchall()
#print result2

row2 = result2[0]
#print 'r1',row[1]
#print 'r2',row2[0]
sql = "SELECT * FROM stobt  WHERE stid = '%d'" % (row2)
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
row = results[1]
tc = 56
for row in results:

   if row2[0] == row[1]:
      idd = row[0]
      stid = row[1]
      obtained = row[2]
      subject = row[3]

   # Now print fetched result
      print "id=%s,stid=%s,obtained=%f,subject=%s" % \
             (idd, stid, obtained, subject )

    #  if obtained <= 50:
     #    if tc >= 50:
      #      print tc
db.close()
```

Its pretty big error and since i cannot understand so i have to force to place the whole error (from web page).

Error:

```
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 C:\New folder\cgi-bin\cgitestsql.py in ()
     13 print (p)
     14 
=>   15 import MySQLdb
     16 
     17 db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=3306, user="root", passwd="",db="project")
MySQLdb undefined
 c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-trjky9\MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\MySQLdb\__init__.py in ()
 c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-trjky9\MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\_mysql.py in ()
 c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-trjky9\MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\_mysql.py in __bootstrap__()
 C:\New folder\cgi-bin\build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py in resource_filename(self=<pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance>, package_or_requirement='_mysql', resource_name='_mysql.pyd')
 C:\New folder\cgi-bin\build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py in get_resource_filename(self=<pkg_resources.ZipProvider instance>, manager=<pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance>, resource_name='_mysql.pyd')
 C:\New folder\cgi-bin\build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py in _extract_resource(self=<pkg_resources.ZipProvider instance>, manager=<pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance>, zip_path='_mysql.pyd')
 C:\New folder\cgi-bin\build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py in get_cache_path(self=<pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance>, archive_name='mysql_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg', names=['_mysql.pyd'])
 C:\New folder\cgi-bin\build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py in extraction_error(self=<pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance>)
<class 'pkg_resources.ExtractionError'>: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg cache: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Windows\\Application Data' The Python egg cache directory is currently set to: C:\Windows\Application Data\Python-Eggs Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory? You can change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable to point to an accessible directory. 
      args = ("Can't extract file(s) to egg cache\n\nThe followin...nt\nvariable to point to an accessible directory.\n",) 
      cache_path = r'C:\Windows\Application Data\Python-Eggs' 
      manager = <pkg_resources.ResourceManager instance> 
      message = "Can't extract file(s) to egg cache\n\nThe followin...nt\nvariable to point to an accessible directory.\n" 
      original_error = WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied')
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Don't use CGI, and don't use raw SQL; *especially* don't use string substitution to pass query params into SQL. Use a web framework.

Comment: thnx for response i cannot use framework right now because i am now standing on final stage of my project. It was my immature thinking but now i am glued with this.....

Comment: The error message is talking about permissions. It suggests setting `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` environment variable to a directory you know you can write to, did you try this? If that doesn't work, can you try running as administrator?